# Proper use of assert() in c++

Tags: c++, assert, assertion, invariants

My professor gave us a exercise where we have to decide when it's appropriate to use the assert(check_inv()) that keeps the objected in a state well-formed respecting the class invariant.

I'm not sure when it's necessary to check the class invariant, i know that before returning a object from his constructor is a good practice checking the class invariant, but in case of other functions i'm not completely sure.

this is the exam text:

```
class C
{ 

    public: 

        bool check_inv() const 
        { 
            // Implementation of class invariant code
        }

        C(int a, int b)
        { 
            // Implementation of class constructor.
        }
        void foo(C& y)
        {
            // Implementation of method foo. 
        }
        void bar(const C& y)
        { 
             // Implementation of method bar.
        }
        void ying(const C& y)
        { 
            // Implementation of method ying. 
        }
        void yang(const C& y) const
         { 
             // Implementation of method yang.
         }
        ~C()
         { 
             // Implementation of class destructor.
         }
        static void zen(int i, double d) 
        { 
            //Implementation of method zen.
        }
// ... Some other code ...
}; // class C
```

Where should i check the class invariant?

EDIT: this isn't supposed to be homework question at all, i just need to understand the functioning of assertions through an example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework.

Comment: @Benoit That is not a Close reason by itself. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: If you want to do it really safe you could check at the start of every function and every time you leave a function that might have modified the object.

Comment: I presume that by the time your code is in release mode, you know there is no possible way to fail the `assert`? Since at that stage, it will be removed and cannot catch any error states that arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the life cycle of an object: it gets created by a constructor, it gets examined by `const` member functions, it gets modified by non-`const` member functions, and eventually it gets destroyed by its destructor. So as far as the class invariant goes, it must be satisfied at the end of the constructor and at the end of any non-`const` member functions. That's sufficient to ensure that the invariant is satisfied everywhere. Checking it on entry into a function doesn't make the class robust; it might detect overwrites from outside, but that's not part of the abstraction that the class presents. So: check the invariant at the end of each constructor and at the end of each non-`const` member function.

Comment: ok that's very helpful thanks you! should i also check invariant on non-const objects passed by parameter? for example in method "foo" should i check invariant on "y"? 

and last, should i behave in the same way for static methods too?

Comment: @n_denny - if you're adding asserts out of fear that objects will somehow get corrupted, then put them everywhere. If you're adding asserts as a discipline to ensure that an object's **member functions** do not corrupt the state of the object, what, if anything, is gained by checking an object that's passed by reference, and what, if anything, is gained by checking something in a static member function?

Answer (score 0):

Possible you should checking the class invariant in all other public class member functions except destructor function.And you should check twice, first after enter the function, then before exit the function, while between this two process, you can do sth to invariant.

Comment: Disagree. What's the reason to not check invariant at end of ctor? It should be fulfilled there. This might not be true for the dtor because that can be called at any time, but that is another thing.

Comment: @WernerHenze Yes, you are right.I delete that. Then what's the difference in dtor?

Comment: If you are doing a change to an object you might have a situation where you start with a valid invariant, then break it, then reassure it. If in the time where the invariant is not true an exception occurs and the program needs to terminate or delete the object, then your dtor gets called. The dtor should handle that. Of course depending on the object you might be able to assure that your dtor will never be called an objects for which the invariant is not true.

Comment: @WernerHenze Got it. Thank you.